# How to create a custom connected neural network using tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I want to create a network that has specific fixed connections between layers.
For example,
[Sparsely connected neural network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFGBJ.png)

I tried looking into functions in Tensorflow, but I only found dense networks with regularizers, which doesn't function as I want.

If it's not possible in tensorflow, then please suggest some other library that can be used. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can always find a workaround. Let's say a layer does `y = xW` (`Wx` is also correct) but you want some of the entries in `W` always be zeros. You can do it column-wise:

For column `i` (or element `i` since `y` is a vector) of the output, `y_i = x * D_i * W_i`. The matrix `D_i` is a constant diagonal matrix (`tf.constant`, `tf.diag`) that controls what element would be zeros.

Then you can use `tf.concat` to combine all `y_i` to matrix `Y`.

You can abstract this into a function whose signature may look like `def sparse_layer(input_layer, gates_matrix, activation_f, ...)` which returns the output layer.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to implement this and see the results..
One question though, if we force the weights to go to zero like this, how does back-propagation affect these weights then? The ideal situation in my case would be that the gradients do not propagate back to the weights that are zero.

Comment: This method is not working. This way the network still try to train the weights on the connection that are not supposed to be there. We need a network where weights for the connected edges are the only variables to be trained. Any suggestions?

Comment: @navyajapani Let's expand the expression and we have `y_i = x * D_i * W_i = [....x....] * diag([....d....]) * transpose([....w....])`. If `d = 0`, then `y_i = [....0....] * transpose([....w...]) = .... + 0*w + ....`. So the element `w` in `W` has on impact on the output, so the gradient with respect to `w` is 0 and therefore `w` is not trained even though it may have its initial value.

Comment: It worked by making initialization also sparse. Thanks.. :)